# Scalar type in torch.where?

Tags: pytorch

[torch.where documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html) states that `x` and `y` can be either a tensor or a scalar. However, it doesn't seem to support float32 scalar.

```py
import torch

x = torch.randn(3, 2)  # x is of type torch.float32

torch.where(x>0, 0, x)  # RuntimeError: expected scalar type long long but found float 
# torch.where(x>0, 0.0, x)  # RuntimeError: expected scalar type double but found float
```

My question is how to use float32 scalar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that `torch` doesn't support `float32`. It's your system doesn't provide an easy way to specify `0` as a `float32`. As stated in the errors, `0` is interpreted as a `long long` C type, i.e. `int64`, while `0.0` is interpreted as `double` C type, i.e. `float64`.

I guess you need to cast `0` to the same `dtype` with that of `x`:

```
torch.where(x>0.0, torch.tensor(0, dtype=x.dtype), x)
```

Comment: Thanks! So two follow up questions:
1. is there a way to create a float32 scaler in python?
2. If I use torch.where(x>0.0, torch.tensor(0, dtype=x.dtype), x) as you suggested, I got this error `RuntimeError: Expected condition, x and y to be on the same device, but condition is on cuda:0 and x and y are on cpu and cuda:0 respectively`. Do I have to do manual device management?

Comment: @HongtaoYang 1) I don't know a direct way. `np.float32` is an option, but that would be redundant since you are pushing to `torch` anyway. 2) pass `device=x.device` to `torch.tensor(0,...)`.

Comment: That solves the problem, thanks! I just feel it is a little too verbose than necessary. If I can use scaler, device placement is automatic, I would expect the same for tensor.

Comment: @HongtaoYang Also check out `torch.zeros_like(x)`. That’ll be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue issue in torch 1.9.0 (and potentially earlier versions) where type promotion does not occur.  See [issue #64161](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/64161).  This is listed as a high priority issue with initial patches written.